# How to split string at comma but keep white spaces?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, concatenation

How to split string at comma so that it keeps all spaces. Example:

```
Input: ["  hello  , world  "]
```

Need to separate this in array so that it looks like this:

```
Array[0] = "  hello  "
Array[1] = " world  "
```

and after connecting them:

```
Output: "  hello   world  "
```

Tried using split like this: `input.split("\\s*,\\s*"))` but then I get it separated without white space...

```
Array[0] = "hello"
Array[1] = "world"
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: `input.split(",")`

Comment: If you're going to join them again, why not just `replaceAll` `","` with `""`?

Comment: Curious : why would you think `input.split("\\s*,\\s*"))` would do what you expect?

Comment: thanks .split(",") helped. Don't know, had some problems with split(",") before, so I forgot to try it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = " hello , world ";
String s1[] = s.split(",");
System.out.println(s1[0]+s1[1]);
```

Output:

```
 hello  world
```